# Reintegrating branch made from working directory

Tags: svn, branch, merge

I have just done something without thinking it through.  I have made a branch from working directory containing local modifications using TortoisSVN.  I am assuming it did a copy and switch in one shot.  Now the first version of my new branch is different from any version of the trunk.  The question is, how do I reintegrate this branch back into the trunk?  If I use the delta between the first and the last versions of the branch, that changeset will not contain the initial modifications that I had in my working directory.

If I had made a branch from the latest version of the trunk, and then committed my local changes, this would not have been a problem, because the first version of the branch would have been identical to the corresponding version of the trunk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose I can find the version of the trunk, just before I made the branch and use that as the starting point of the changeset.  Seems awkward though.  Is there a more elegant solution?

Edit: yes there is a more elegant solution.  I was wrong.  A branch, even a branch created from the working directory retains all the history of the trunk prior to the split.  I am using TortoisSVN, so all I had to do was uncheck "Stop on copy/rename" in the log window to see the versions prior to the split.  Then I simply used the version immediately before the creation of the branch as the start of my change set.  There was no problem after all.

Comment: More elegant would be not to commit changes and create branch at the same step. Since you done that I guess there is little you can do to improve this process.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you.

I'm calling your new branch `invalid` to shorten things up a bit.

1. Make a diff between `invalid` branch and trunk (use the revision just before creating new invalid branch - let's call this one `invalid`) - that will give you changes from your working copy that you commited when creating invalid branch and are not part of a `trunk`.
2. Apply those changes to trunk.
3. Reintegrate your `invalid` branch with `trunk` (initial changes are already there - step 2)

Comment: In this case, why do I need two merges?  Merging in the delta between the trunk version just before the branch was created and the HEAD of the invalid branch would produce the same result.